# Reading CSV files into R

Tags: r, excel, csv, read.csv

I am trying to read an excel file into R using `read.csv`. But I keep getting an error message stating

`Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection`

I wrote `mydata1 <- read.csv("birthdays.csv", header = TRUE)`.

Comment: format your error please

Comment: Please, run `getwd()` to check if you are trying to load from the correct directory.